# WatchKit Sound from watch speaker without displaying controls

Tags: swift, audio, controls, watchkit, speaker

this has probably been covered before.

I can play sound through the watch speaker (as long as no bluetooth device is connected). But it brings up the annoying controls.

I want to play sound with no controls on a button press.

Is there a way of hiding the controls?
[image]

```
    let assetURL: NSURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("Sound", withExtension: "wav")!

@IBAction func buttonAction() {
         self.presentMediaPlayerControllerWithURL(assetURL, options: nil, completion: { _ in })
}
```